# ARRAY PHP How to put variables in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi guys i would like to ask help on my problem..

I have 4 variables made from my query:

```
$sql1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(NOW()) AND order_action = 'Online Transaction' "));

$sql2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(NOW()) AND order_action = 'Walkin Transaction' "));

$sql3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(NOW())-1 AND  order_action = 'Online Transaction' "));

$sql4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(NOW())-1 AND  order_action = 'Walkin Transaction' "));
```

I would like to put them in an array..to be exactly on my expectations.

Here is my sample code:

```
$stack = array($sql1, $sql2);
array_push($stack, $sql3, $sql4);
$query = print_r($stack);
$result = $query;


print json_encode($result);
```

It display like this on my browser:
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 8 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 ) true

But i want to display it like this:
[{"0","1"},
{"2","3"}]

I am planning to make a line graph on this.. I have a Chart.min.js and jquery.min.js

If any way.. The whole point.. i want to make a line graph that would compare my data from current year to last year.

Help me pls. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try

```
<?php
$a = array(0,8,0,1) ;
echo "<pre>";print_r(json_encode(array_chunk($a, 2)));
?>
```

with that. You can get this result

```
[[0,8],[0,1]]
```

Btw, Why you need to do that with your array ? .

Edited

After i check your question again, So you want get the `order`

```
<?php
$stack = array(0,8,0,1) ;

$array2= array();
foreach ($stack  as $key => $val) {
   $array2[] = $key;
}

echo "<pre>";print_r(json_encode(array_chunk($array2, 2)));

?>
```